# Geolocation of L2G-Lite MODIS data

Tags: coordinate-system, remote-sensing, modis

I would like to know if I am processing an L2G-Lite MODIS product, do I still need to geolocate, or reproject it to EPSG:4326? Or can I just leave it?

Answer (score 1):

L2G-lite format contains MODIS data projected to the MODIS Sinusoidal Grid. You could visualize it as an array but for any mapping purpose you would probably want to reproject it to a different coordinate system.